# Get Email that email was piped to

Tags: php, email

I have a script that is called from a email pipe.
So someone emails abc@example.com, and it goes to here

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);
// empty vars
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
if ($splittingheaders) {
// this is a header
$headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
// look out for special headers
if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
$subject = $matches[1];
}
if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
$from = $matches[1];
}
} else {
// not a header, but message
$message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
}
if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
// empty line, header section has ended
$splittingheaders = false;
}
}
?>
```

How can I get the email it was sent to? in this case I want $to = 'abc@example.com';
but 'abc' could be anything, so I mostly want the username from the email address.

Sorry if that doesn't make sense or is noobish, i'm new to this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the Envelope-to header

You can edit your code to include `preg_match("/^Envelop-to: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)`

Viewing the source code of emails sent to you is a great resource.

Comment: there is no such thing... the source shows "(envelope-from <example@gmail.com>)" only

Comment: found "To: " by viewing the source, so you get the √